# how to find record by array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's suppose

```
class Sale< ApplicationRecord

    serialize :items, Array

end
```

How do you search based on array property. The items is a list of integers or ids.

Now i want to find out all Sale records which has inside its items array a particular id.

Let's say i want to search for id 10

how can i achieve it using where? I am looking for something similar to

```
Sale.where(items: Array.new(10))
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the same by creating a new relationship `Sale has_many Items` and then you could use [find](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class) passing an array of id's.

```
class Sale < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :items
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :items
end

sale = Sale.first()
sale.items.find([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]) // returns an array with the matching items
```

Answer (score 0):

`Sale.where("items = ANY(ARRAY[?]::int[])", [10])`

note, `int` should be replaced with your `items` field type (I guess it's `int` already)